# Rigorous mathematical proof of the equation of motion of a Sliding Chain with friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In most physics textbooks the sliding chain is considered a one dimensional problem, where every force applied to the chain in the x or y axes is immediately summed to calculate the net force (As if we were dealing with a pulley that connects to masses using a massless rope). I was wondering if there is a more rigorous explanation of why that is possible. I tried to work it out by myself wanted to know if my proof is sufficient.

Let $\rho $ be the density of the chain and $l$ its constant length. Let
also $x$ be the part of the chain laying on the table and $y$ the part
of the chain hanging over the table.

The mass on top of the table and hanging from the table varies, so

$$\frac{d}{dt} ( \rho  x \dot{x} ) = - \mu g \rho x
\frac{\dot{x}}{|\dot{x}|} \tag{1}$$  (for motion with sliding friction)
for the $x$ direction with the unit vector pointing to the right

$ \frac{d}{dt} ( \rho  y \dot{y} ) =  g  \rho y \tag{2}$

for the y direction with the unit vector pointing downwards.

There is also
$ x + y = l \tag{3}$
and therefore
$\dot{x} = -\dot{y} \tag{4}$.
If we subtract  (2) from (1) we get
$\frac{d}{dt} ( x \dot{x} - y \dot{y} ) = - g y - \mu g x
\frac{\dot{x}}{|\dot{x}|} $.

After substituting x in (3) and (4) we get

$\ddot{y} = \frac{g}{l} y - \frac{\mu g}{l} (l - y)
\frac{\dot{y}}{|\dot{y}|}  \tag{5}$.

With $\frac{\dot{y}}{|\dot{y}|}=1$ we get

$\ddot{y} = \frac{g}{l} y - \frac{\mu g}{l} (l - y) \tag{6}$

which is the DE of the sliding chain with friction.

[image: Sliding Chain]

Comment: Hi! What exactly is your question? *Check my work, please?*

Comment: I posted it as an answer to a question other people may have too since it is not mentioned anywhere. And yes, it is also a "check my work" post, because I want to know if people agree that this is a more rigorous way to approach this problem.

Comment: I've solved the DE $(6)$ and the solution appears correct to me. But I don't follow everything in your derivation. What does $\frac{\dot{x}}{|\dot{x}|}$ *physically* represent, for instance?

Comment: The sliding friction is always in the opposite direction of the velocity. And $\frac{\dot{x}}{|\dot{x}|}$ is the unit vector pointing in the direction of the velocity. So - $\frac{\dot{x}}{|\dot{x}|}$ is the direction of the sliding friction.

Comment: I've now done the derivation of the DE independently and found the same result as you. However, we might be overlooking something. The sudden change in direction at the corner requires a centripetal force to keep the chain "bound" to the corner.

Comment: suppose there is no friction on the quarter circle. Replace $l$ with $ l
- \frac{2 \pi R}{4}=l'$ where $R$ is the radius

of the quarter circle. Equation (4) is still valid.  the only change in
(6) is to replace $l$ with $l'$, which does not change

the solution for $y$

Comment: a second approach would be to say that $R$ is small compared to $l$ so
that $ l - \frac{2 \pi R}{4} \approx l'$, without friction on the
quarter circle.

Comment: Yes, I agree. My derivation of $(6)$ was considerably shorter than yours but obtained the exact same result.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you shared your way of approaching the problem if you don't mind! Getting your opinions is one of the reasons I made this post.

Comment: Ok. I'll do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Two forces that are relevant to potential acceleration act on the chain: gravity $\vec{G}$ on the $y$ part and a friction force $\vec{F}$ on the $x$ part. The latter arises from the Normal force. The vectors point in different directions but the corner acts as a frictionless pulley, 'transmitting' these forces and allowing us to use their scalars.

So we can write, as equation of motion:

$$ma=G-F$$

Filling in we get:

$$\rho l \ddot{y}=y\rho g-\mu \rho gx$$

And:

$$x+y=l \Rightarrow x=l-y$$

So:

$$ l \ddot{y}=gy-\mu gl+\mu gy$$

With minimal reworking this becomes OP's equation $(6)$:
$$\ddot{y} = \frac{g}{l} y - \frac{\mu g}{l} (l - y)\tag{6}$$

In turn this reworks easily to:

$$\ddot{y} = \frac{g(1+\mu)}{l}y-\mu g\tag{7}$$

---

**Initial condition:**

Only if $G-F>0$ does acceleration occur, so:

$$y\rho g-\mu \rho gx>0$$

$$y -\mu(l-y)>0$$
$$y>\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}l\tag{8}$$
So this is the minimum amount of chain that needs to dangle over the edge at $t=0$, to get acceleration.

---

**Solving the DE:**
This is outside the remit of the question but I was curious to see what form the solution of $(7)$ would take.

$$\ddot{y} = \frac{g(1+\mu)}{l}y-\mu g\tag{7}$$
Make a substitution:
$$\frac{g(1+\mu)}{l}y-\mu g=u$$
$$\frac{g(1+\mu)}{l}\dot{y}=\dot{u}$$
$$\frac{g(1+\mu)}{l}\ddot{y}=\ddot{u}$$
$$\ddot{y}=\frac{l}{g(1+\mu)}\ddot{u}$$
$$\frac{l}{g(1+\mu)}\ddot{u}-u=0$$
$$\ddot{u}-\frac{g(1+\mu)}{l}u=0$$
$$\ddot{u}-m^2u=0$$

Where:

$$m^2=\frac{g(1+\mu)}{l}$$
The solution is of the shape:
$$u=c_1 e^{mt}+c_2 e^{-mt}$$
Where the boundary conditions can be:
$$y=y_0, t=0$$
$$\dot{y}=0, t=0$$
So the acceleration is far from uniform, as is the case for free falling body (of constant mass).